# Parse time string (MM:SS.msec)

Tags: ruby, parsing, time

I am trying to parse a time (without date) like `"07:15.352"` to a `Time` object. I am expecting something like:

```
2016-04-11 17:07:15 +352
```

or better something like:

```
2016-04-11 17:07:15.352  || 2016-04-11 17:07:15:352
```

I have tried all the possibilities without any success. Tested:

```
time = Time.strptime("07:15.352", "%M:%S")
# => 2016-04-11 17:07:15 +0200
```

Not working.

```
time = Time.strptime("07:15.352", "%M:%S.%L")
# => 2016-04-11 17:07:15 +0200
```

Not working. The result of the milliseconds given are not the same as the input string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `%H:%M.%L` template since you working with this specific format:

```
time = Time.strptime("07:15.352", "%H:%M.%L")
#=> 2016-04-11 07:15:00
time.strftime("%H:%M.%L")
#=> "07:15.352"
```